# How can I insert degree symbol to attribute table in feature class?

Tags: arcpy, python, cursor, encoding

I am trying to insert a bearing string into an attribute table, 
I want the string to look like this -> S 58°15'31" W ,
but what I am getting in the table is this -> S 58Â°15'31" W

The code I am using is in a ArcMap toolbox.tbx

Here is the function I am using to create the bearing string

```
def returnBearingString(azimuth):
bearing=None
dmsbearing=None
if azimuth>270 and azimuth<=360:
    bearing = 360 - azimuth
    dmsbearing=ddToDms(bearing)
    dmsbearing = """N {0}°{1}'{2}" W""".format(int(dmsbearing[0]),int(dmsbearing[1]),int(round(dmsbearing[2],0)))
    return dmsbearing
if azimuth>=0 and azimuth<=90:
    dmsbearing=ddToDms(azimuth)
    dmsbearing = """N {0}°{1}'{2}" E""".format(int(dmsbearing[0]),int(dmsbearing[1]),int(round(dmsbearing[2],0)))
    return dmsbearing
if azimuth>90 and azimuth<=180:
    bearing= 180 - azimuth
    dmsbearing=ddToDms(bearing)
    dmsbearing = """S {0}°{1}'{2}" E""".format(int(dmsbearing[0]),int(dmsbearing[1]),int(round(dmsbearing[2],0)))
    return dmsbearing
if azimuth>180 and azimuth<=270:
    bearing = azimuth-180
    dmsbearing=ddToDms(bearing)
    dmsbearing = """S {0}°{1}'{2}" W""".format(int(dmsbearing[0]),int(dmsbearing[1]),int(round(dmsbearing[2],0)))
    return dmsbearing
```

Here is the function I am using to convert dd to dms

```
def ddToDms(dd):
negative = dd<0
dd=abs(dd)
minutes,seconds = divmod(dd*3600,60)
degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
if negative:
    if degrees>0:
        degrees = -degrees
    elif minutes>0:
        minutes = -minutes
    else:
        seconds = -seconds
return (int(degrees),int(minutes),round(seconds,3))
```

Here is how I am using it to write to feature class.

```
ic = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(leaseRoadSegment.name,["OBJECTID","SHAPE@","BEARING_STRING"])
bear  = returnBearingString(az)
newRow = 6000,polyShape,bear
ic.insertRow(newRow)
```

where the azimuth is just a number between 0 and 360.

Comment: Perhaps review https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/240489/115

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to add the Header

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

before I added the script to the toolbox, I added the header after and it didn't affect the encoding until I deleted and then added the script to the toolbox again,